# If my paper was published in IEEE Xplore, can I upload it to arXiv

Tags: arxiv, preprint

A research paper from a computer vision conference I made was published in IEEE Xplore, but also in some other places (where it is open).

Can I publish it to arXiv?

[paper in IEEE Xplore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7813058/)

[paper in Conference Repo](http://sibgrapi.sid.inpe.br/rep/sid.inpe.br/sibgrapi/2016/07.18.20.42?mirror=sid.inpe.br/banon/2001/03.30.15.38.24&metadatarepository=sid.inpe.br/sibgrapi/2016/07.18.20.42.24)

Comment: sorry, I honestly tried to find but couldn't

Comment: No problem :) It's not meant as a slap on the wrist, just as a notice that the community has already answered the question. Congrats on the paper!